# Why does changing texture change it for both objects?

Tags: unity, textures, materials

I have two identical objects in my Unity scene. When I change the texture of one, the texture is changed on the other, almost as though the first one is a prefab. Why is this happening and how can I treat them independently?

Steps taken:

- Import .obj file and two .png files
- Drag object into scene
- Look at the object in the hierarchy (where the list of all objects in the scene is)
- It has a child called pSphere1
- pSphere1 has a mesh renderer with 2 materials on it - RedGold and pSphere1Mat
- It also has two components controlling each of these materials
- In those control components, I can select a shader from the dropdown and I can also select a texture.
- For either one of them, if I change the texture say to PolkaDots, both objects have their materials changed, instead of only the one I am working on.

[image: two RedGold balls, how do I make one PolkaDot?]

Comment: Both use the same material?

Comment: @bummzack added an image to try make it clearer

Comment: The image doesn't help much. But the reason for your problem is most likely that both objects use the same material...

Answer (score 2):

If you modify a material, it affects the objects that are using it. You need to duplicate that material, modify its texture and reassign it to the target object.

Comment: Thanks that explains a LOT! My only difficulty now is that I don't know how to duplicate material. I have located it in my project, but when I right-click, I don't see a way to duplicate? Do you mind expanding your answer?

Comment: (All I have access to is the .obj and .png files from the artist so I can't just reimport and give it a different name)

Comment: @d3vid Just create a new one and apply the new properties to it. If you have further problems, ask a new question.

Comment: trying it out based on http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Material.html

Comment: select the material from your object browser and perform copy paste. it  will duplicate the material and identify the new object as "<material name>(1)"